# How do I use a while loop with a random function generator in python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I need to use a while loop with the choice function to terminate when a specific element in a list is randomly selected

I have successfully called the choice() function to select a random element but I get an infinite loop when I try to add a while loop

```
from random import *


while choice != 3:

    choice([1,2,3,4,5,6])

    print(choice)

    print('damn!')
```

I get an infinite loop.  I need to print all randomly generated numbers that are not the condition for termination of the while loop.  When the termination condition is reached a string is displayed and the program terminates

Comment: You never assigned anything to `choice`. BTW, using the same name for avariable as function name is a bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some issues in your code.

1. Your variable name `choice` shadows the function [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice), so it's better to use another variable name like `my_choice`
2. You need to assign the output of `choice` to the variable in order to use it.
3. You should also avoid using star imports, i.e. `import *` if you are only planning to use one function from the module (Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad) question for more details on why it's bad)

Once you do those changes, your code will work fine

```
from random import choice

#Variable to hold choice
my_choice = 0

while my_choice != 3:

    #Assign return value of choice
    my_choice = choice([1,2,3,4,5,6])

    print(my_choice)

print('damn!')
print(my_choice)
```

A sample output will be

```
5
1
3
damn!
3
```